# YubiKey 5Ci - Don't receive USB Type-C attach/detach notification on one iPad Pro

Tags: ios, notifications, yubikey

We have integrated YubiKey 5Ci (PIV) support into our iOS mobile app.

USB Type-C integration is done using Apple CryptoTokenKit (TKSmartCard classes). This works fine.

For attached/detached notification, we are using TKTokenWatcher as below:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [watcher setInsertionHandler:^(NSString *tokenID)
         {
            // Hack to read name if there's only one smart card
            LOGARG(BAI_LOG_DEBUG, "Token %s inserted.", [tokenID UTF8String]);
            //Call deviceAdded() only when tokenID is not APPLE_DEFAULT_TOKENID i.e. com.apple.*
            if ([tokenID rangeOfString:APPLE_DEFAULT_TOKENID].location == NSNotFound)
                [self typeCDeviceAdded];
            
            [watcher addRemovalHandler:^(NSString *tokenID) {
              LOGARG(BAI_LOG_DEBUG, "Token %s removed.", [tokenID UTF8String]);
                //Call deviceRemoved() only when tokenID is not APPLE_DEFAULT_TOKENID i.e. com.apple.*
                if ([tokenID rangeOfString:APPLE_DEFAULT_TOKENID].location != NSNotFound)
                    [self typeCDeviceRemoved];
            } forTokenID:tokenID];
        }];
    }
```

This works well on an iPad Pro, 5th generation and OS 16.3.1 however it does not work with another iPad Pro, 4th generation and OS 16.1.

### Log trace statements on iPad#1:

```
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.yubico.Authenticator.TokenExtension:D737C5B76432A24620B1287F54A943FC1A418CA5F70C9F26E31ECD2BAED7EBD2 inserted.
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.apple.secelemtoken inserted.
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.apple.pivtoken:E658E6D40E7508CE2A666D35B3048C70 inserted.
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.apple.setoken inserted.
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.apple.setoken:aks inserted.
```

### Log trace statements on iPad#2:

```
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.apple.pivtoken:39BDF66093B0B304408E2805E35BFE84 inserted.
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.apple.secelemtoken inserted.
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.apple.setoken inserted.
[ReaderInterface init]_block_invoke Token com.apple.setoken:aks inserted.
```

You can see, we are getting attachment notifications from com.yubico.Authenticator.TokenExtension on iPad#1 but not with iPad#2.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Any suggestions for troubleshooting?